# jquery function works with live, not with on

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to use the preferred on method call but the code is not working with *on* but does work with the *live* method.

Okay, I have a simple button element.

```
<button id="EditVal" name="EditVal" style="btn" value="Edit Debt">Edit Debt </button>
```

If I use the live method this code works:

```
$("#EditVal").live("click", function(e){
    alert('Edit this Val');
})
```

But this doesn't

```
$("#EditVal").on("click", function(e){
    alert('Edit this Val');
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the jQuery version you are using? Make sure it is 1.7+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dynamically dropping a html element on the page then you need live. Here is why, on is set to work on EditVal if EditVal exsists on pageload. Since it does not I am assuming, the live function is needed as that can be bounded late after the initial page load. I think that was the original thought behind live in the first place. Any particular reason why you are using on instead of live?

Comment: One should try to use `delegate` rather than `live`.

Comment: I thought that on was supposed to be the preferred method instead of live as of jq 1.7 to consolidate the live and delegate functionality

Comment: @MichaelBW It is. rich.okelly means use `delegate` instead of `live` for < jQuery 1.7, otherwise use `on`.

Comment: Of course all the answers were correct.  This helped me understand why it works the way it does the best.  Thanks for all your help, stackoverflowers.

Answer (score 9):

You're using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), not like [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). To use it like `live()`, you should write:

```
$(document).on("click", "#EditVal", function(e) {
    alert('Edit this Val');
});
```

Note that, for performance reasons, it's preferred to call `on()` on a non-dynamic ancestor element instead of `document`, i.e. to use it like [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `live()`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `on` as you are attaches the event on page load. As you are dynamically loading the content, you need to use `on` as you would `delegate` by placing the handler on a parent element, and passing a filtering selector.

Try this:

```
$("#ParentOfEditVal").on("click", "#EditVal", function(e){
    alert('Edit this Val');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic is that .on() binds the event to an object that is in the DOM. Then you give, as a parameter, the selector to find the child-element you want the trigger the event.

```
$("#parent_has_to_be_in_dom").on("click", "#myButton", function(event) {
    // should work like live
    alert("well hello");
});
```